# Problems with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

In my script I want to get Exchange Online distribution group members to my array `$members_id`.

I want to run the cmdlet `Get-DistributionGroupMember` on a remote server so it looks like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    $members_id = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "power_shell_test"
} -ArgumentList $members_id
```

After running this I get an error:

> The syntax is not supported by this runspace. This can occur if the runspace is in no-language mode.

[image]

When I delete `$members_id =` it runs good.

Please tell me if you have an idea why it works like that.

Comment: I'd say "Problems with Invoke-Command" is not a meaningful title...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're getting the error (it's probably because of how you opened `$Session`), but if you want the output of a remote command `Get-DistributionGroupMember` in a local variable `$members_id` you need to change your code to something like this:

```
$members_id = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "power_shell_test"
}
```

Use `-ArgumentList` only if you want to pass the ID of the group whose members you want resolved into the scriptblock. You can either assign the parameters to variables inside the scriptblock with a `Param()` directive:

```
$members_id = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    Param($id)
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $id
} -ArgumentList $group_id
```

or use the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$args`:

```
$members_id = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $args[0]
} -ArgumentList $group_id
```

Alternatively you could access variables outside the scriptblock via the `using:` [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-3.0):

```
$members_id = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $using:group_id
}
```